# EF Code-First table per type with base class DbSet

Tags: .net, inheritance, mapping, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have a DbSet in the DataContext for the base class:

```
public DbSet<BaseClass> Users {get;set;}
```

I have 2 derived classes client and driver.

Both have an foreign key AdminID.

When I get data for a specific type there is no problem.

```
Users.OfType<Client>.ToList()
```

However if i try to get both Clients and Drivers something gets messed up in the code generation:

```
Users.ToList()
```

the AdminID property is generated 2 times.

AdminID and AdminID1.

I think the sql generator gets confused because I have the AdminID in both dervied classes but not in the parent.

I cannot put this property in the parent because I have another derived class that does not have this property.

Is this a bug or am i doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not bug. It is feature = limitation. Once you move property to derived class it must have unique mapping to database column. Because of that you cannot have shared AdminId between two derived classes. Each class will have its own foreign key column and relation.